# Library for skeleton joint extraction with Kinect

Tags: c++, kinect

I've done a few things with the Microsoft Research Kinect SDK. Getting the skeleton is super-easy and I'd like to do something similar in the context of a **commercial** project.

What is the best C++ library that is available today (even if that's not free / open source)?

Comment: do you mean an alternative for MS Kinect SDK?

Comment: Yes, because it's not available for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has published a commercial version of Kinect SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenNI + NITE seems to be an option but I could not find any explicit mention of commercial usage on the website.

Comment: [here](http://www.brekel.com/?page_id=671) it is said to be "icense includes commercial use"

Comment: Thanks, but an unofficial blog post is not authoritative, especially when it's the only source.